# Angular CLI and Stripe

Tags: stripe-payments, angular-cli

Is there a way to install Stripe checkout using Angular CLI? I tried installing as a [3rd party library](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli#3rd-party-library-installation) but that didn't work

Answer (score 0):

```
npm i angular-stripe-checkout
```

The angular CLI does not install packages.